# Unlocalized SC2 version for localized server

Tags: starcraft-2

Can I use the English version of Starcraft 2 to play on a localized server (for example Russian)?

If yes what should I do for it? Where can I download an English version of Starcraft 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking if you can play the English version of Starcraft 2 on a non-English server (eg. SEA), then the answer is: No.

If you're asking if you can play the English version on a non-Blizzard server, that question is beyond the scope of gaming.se and you'll have to go else where for an answer.

Comment: I'm asking about blizzard servers :(

Comment: @Sly sorry I couldn't tell from your phrasing

Comment: You should mention that it's "beyond the scope.." because it's illegal (or at least against the ToS)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot play the game in a region where a certain language is not available when you purchase it.

I had that very same problem, and after a lot of mail exchanges with blizzard support, the asked me to post the request in the forums, [and so I did](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/628259047).

You can show your support in that thread and in the many others about the same topic, and perhaps someday it'll be possible.